# Do you know some service to generate PDF online?

Tags: pdf, export

I'm looking for an online service to design and export a PDF from a source of data (Maybe a csv). I need to export PDFs with some basic data, like name an addresses for ~1500 registers in a database. I know webmerge, and is exactly what I need, but the price is high for my needs, like $200

Do you know an alternative to [webmerge](https://www.webmerge.me/examples)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Google Docs.
Check them here: [Google Docs](https://www.google.com/docs/about/)

You can import your .csv files to Google Sheets and export then as .pdf.
Also, you can import many other file formats like .doc, .docx etc.

Comment: I Found a google docs plugin to combine data from a spreadsheet to a doc. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what this is designed for but using XML as source data:

http://www.cloudformatter.com/Nimbus